# Adding Fetch button on the project Menu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, gitlab

I am new to GitLab (and ruby on rails too).
I am trying to add a new feature:
I am supposed to add a "`Fetch`" button on the project Menu (where the ssh/http link and download/tags are displayed). The purpose of which is to:

1. check firstly if the `@project.import_url` is set.
2. if set then fetch the parent repository and add to merge request, if any new branch is available.

I have tried to do the same using simple online tutorials and editing the `/app/views/layouts/nav/_project.html.haml` file, also adding the required file in the contexts and config folder. But it didn't seem to work.

If you could tell me series of steps ,it would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest example of that is to look for commits like this one:

"[Added a clone button to support one-click clone](https://github.com/shinyzhu/gitlabhq/commit/aab5ff6d46d10c4407b91779338c4250a48691a7)".

As you can see, more than one `.haml` file is impacted.
This isn't the project menu, but can still give you a starting point.
You should find more information in the [GitLab forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/gitlabhq).